# Using Mac OS X 10.9 lsof launches 5 to 10 processes at a time on its own taking all cpu

Tags: macos, python, postgresql

I am running a MacBook Air 13 (Latest) with 8GB / 512 Flash / Core Intel i7.

Lately shortly after bootup I hear the fans winding at top speed. I checked the top processes and see several instances of lsof and Python consuming 50% CPU each. There are sometimes 6 or 8 and if I kill them they just relaunch. When I check the parent ID of these it looks like it the postgres database which is the parent and it appears to be backing up calendar.

Is there any way to stop this from happening? It's eating up my battery not to mention cycles off of the Air's life. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, and quitting the Adobe Acrobat update fixed the issue.

Comment: what is the correlation between Python and Adobe Acrobat update?